# Linear Constraint in Java

Tags: java, linear-programming, apache-commons-math

I am working with a linear solver in java. (apache.commons.math3) So far the constraints are all taking the form where SUM(solutions) >= myLimit.

```
myConstraint = new LinearConstraint(binaryMap, Relationship.GEQ, myLimit);
```

There is a new constraint requirement for margin and I could use some pointers to implement it as I am not familiar with doing more complex equations in the linear solver.

New Constraint:

```
sum(i_n * mySpend_n/1000) < myTotalDailyUnits * myBillableRate / 1000 * (1 - myMarginTarget)
```